Why we seldon use Fermi Surfaces to explain chemical behaviour?
Chemistry basically involves studying the behavior of electrons in atoms and their consequences. Solid-state physicists deeply study Fermi surfaces, analyzing the three-dimensional behavior of atoms. Why do we not absorb this analysis in explaining chemical phenomena? (such as Iron ionization or metallic bonds)

Which phenomena?

Brillouin zones, Bloch theorem and Fermi surfaces were always a mystery to me, but they definitely were included in my undergrad...

Because we generally do not talk about periodic systems, but molecules.

Well, the fact is that we do actually use it! Any serious course on Solid State Chemistry incorporates the concept of Fermi surfaces, and any application in chemical manufacturing within semiconductor technologies is explained through the use of Fermi-Dirac statistics and the density of states. Both of these concepts rely on the use of Fermi levels and how they shift due to charge carrier concentration gradients (and many other phenomena that I cannot summarize here).
However, this concept is bound to the assumption of a crystal structure and, therefore, any branch of chemistry dealing with fluids, amorphous phases, or soft condensed matter cannot be explained by the aforementioned concepts.
